# WordPress ajax load more not working properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to load more posts via load more button when it will be clicked but its not working properly my first three posts repeat again and again, anyone can help me?

Here is my query which I placed in template file.

```
$paged=get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        $the_queryx = new WP_Query(array(
                                'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
                                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'paged'=>$paged,
                                'post__not_in'=> array($sticky_post_id),
                            )
                        );

                        $the_max_num_pagesx = $the_queryx->max_num_pages;

                        if ($the_queryx->have_posts()) {

                            echo '<div id="post_cat_home" class="row">';
                            while ($the_queryx->have_posts()) {
                                $the_queryx->the_post();

                                get_template_part('loop-templates/content', get_post_format());

                            }
                            echo '</div>';

                            if ($the_max_num_pagesx > 1) {
                                echo '<div class="load-more-posts" style="width:100%; text-align:center;"> 
                <button id="more_posts_home_exb" data-sticky="' . $sticky_post_id . '" data-pages="' . $the_max_num_pagesx . '" data-pn="'.$paged.'" class="btn more_posts"> </button>
                </div>';
                            }

                            /* Restore original Post Data */
                            wp_reset_postdata();

                        }
```

**And here is my ajax script:**

```
$("#more_posts_home_exb").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();// When btn is pressed.
        $(this).attr("disabled", true); // Disable the button, temp.
        var total = $(this).data('pages');
        var sticky = $(this).data('sticky');
        load_posts_home_exb(total, sticky);

    });

    //home exhibitions loading
    function load_posts_home_exb(total, sticky) {

        var pageNumber = 1;
        var ppp = 3; // Post per page

        var str = '&sticky_ignore=' + sticky + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&total=' + total + '&action=more_post_home_exb_ajax';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
            data: str,
            success: function (data) {

                var $data = $(data);
                pageNumber++;
                if ($data.length) {

                    $("#post_cat_home").append($data);
                    $("#more_posts_home_exb").attr("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#more_posts_home_exb").attr("disabled", true);
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });

        return false;
    }
```

**This is my final function file code which function call through via ajax script.**

```
function more_post_home_exb_ajax()
{

    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 3;
   // $paged = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
    $sticky_ignore = (isset($_POST['sticky_ignore'])) ? array($_POST['sticky_ignore']) : '';
    $paged = $_POST['pageNumber'] +1;

    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $loop_template = 'loop-templates/content';

        $args = array(
//            'suppress_filters' => true,
            'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
            'post__not_in' => $sticky_ignore,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'paged' => $paged,
        );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $out = '';

    if ($loop->have_posts()) :
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            get_template_part($loop_template, get_post_format());

        endwhile;
    endif;
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_home_exb_ajax', 'more_post_home_exb_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_home_exb_ajax', 'more_post_home_exb_ajax');
```

> This code works but first three posts repeat when button clicked. Thank you!

Comment: `pageNumber` is local to the function and never incremented, it always requests the same page.

Comment: Thanks for reply i've tested but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried some condition in ajax script and it is working now. ;)

```
//home exhibitions loading
    function load_posts_home_exb(total, sticky) {

        var pageNumber = 0;
        var ppp = 3; // Post per page

        pc_x++;
        pageNumber = pc_x;

        if (total > pageNumber - 1) {

            var str = '&sticky_ignore=' + sticky + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&total=' + total + '&action=more_post_home_exb_ajax';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
                data: str,
                success: function (data) {

                    var $data = $(data);
                    
                    if ($data.length) {

                        $("#post_cat_home").append($data);
                        $("#more_posts_home_exb").attr("disabled", false);
                    } else {
                        $("#more_posts_home_exb").attr("disabled", true);
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }

            });

        }
        else{
            $("#more_posts_home_exb").hide();
        }
        return false;
    }
```